# How to create an instant search in Vue.js when the data is server rendered and not part of Vue data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I create very simple instant search filter based on input field value wherein the data is already displayed?

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/270007/) and I would like the same functionality but I am just worrying if my back end developer will pull the data using PHP to display all the products and that said reactivity will not work.

So what is the best approach to make it work in this scenario?

**Edit:** So without the products data it will be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/270284/) .

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="searchbox">
    <input id="search-product" placeholder="Search Products" v-model="search" >
  </div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <span class="product" v-for="product in filteredList">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6325887?s=120&v=4">
        <span class="price-tag">{{ product.price }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-name" v-bind:data-sku="product.sku">{{ product.productName }}</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
    const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                    search: '',
                    products:[
                        {sku: "SS0001",productName: "alimango buttered",price: "seasonal", productCategory:"seafood specials"},
                        {sku: "SS0002",productName: "alimango steamed",price: "seasonal", productCategory:"seafood specials"},
                        {sku: "SS0003",productName: "chili crab with tomato sauce",price: "seasonal", productCategory:"seafood specials"},
                        {sku: "SS0004",productName: "malaga prito",price: "seasonal", productCategory:"seafood specials"},

                    ]
            },
            computed: {
                filteredList() {
                  return this.products.filter(product => {
                    return product.productName.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
                  })
                }
              }

        });
```

Comment: filter will work at last, so dont worry.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you explain further please? Say for example `products` in `data` in my Vue will be remove then how can I patch it with `computed` property?

Comment: @C2486 it will be just like this https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/270284/

Comment: Do you mean if they are server rendered and not part of your Vue data?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry for making it unclear.

Comment: You might be interested in https://ssr.vuejs.org/

Comment: Why not just tell your backend developer that you want to get the data through an ajax call?  If they are rendering the data on the server then you're doing more work then necessary and it's going to be a hassle to hook it up to Vue.